# Pass checked multiple images from one activity to another

Tags: android, image, listview, checkbox

I have a custom listview with checkbox imageview and textview and there is a button below listview. On clicking of that button i have to pass all the checked item details to another activity and show in other listview. I am able to pass selected value but not able to pass images. Images are in drawable folder. Please help me thanks.

Here is the code:

```
subscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String data = "";
            ArrayList<Item> stList = ((OurServiceAdapter) nAdapter)
              .getAllData();

            for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                Item singleStudent = stList.get(i);
                if (singleStudent.isCheckbox() == true) {
                       name.add(singleStudent.getName().toString());
                       img.add(singleStudent.getImage());
                 data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getName().toString();



                }

               }
              // byte[] imgs = singleStudent.getImage();
               Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOurServices.this, ActivityServicesForm.class);
               intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", name);
               //intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("img", img);
               startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the simple way to this is to get position of checked item and in another activity use switch statement to get correct image

Comment: i am not getting can you give a sample please

Comment: What is the number of photos ? is constant ?

Comment: right now it is 10 but it could be increased

Answer (score 1):

you can pass all image as Integer arrayList :

```
//first : for each imageView inside list you must to set tag ,for example ;
imageView0.setTag(R.drawable.image_0); 
imageView1.setTag(R.drawable.image_1);
.
.
. 
imageViewN.setTag(R.drawable.image_N);
```

now when you press button :

```
ArrayList<Integer> checkedImageSrcId = new ArrayLIst<Integer> ;

for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
            Item singleStudent = stList.get(i);
            if (singleStudent.isCheckbox() == true) {
                   name.add(singleStudent.getName().toString());
                  // img.add(singleStudent.getImage());
                  // you most to get checked imageViews Tag  and i dont have an idea about how to get those
                  checkedImageSrcId.add( getImageViewTagAtPostion(i));
             data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getName().toString();

            }

           }
          // byte[] imgs = singleStudent.getImage();
           Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOurServices.this, ActivityServicesForm.class);
           intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", name);
           intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("img", checkedImageSrcId);
           startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi bro i am using listview so where should i add this tag

Comment: and how to extract this in second activity

Comment: set tag in listView Adapter . where you set imageView drawable src ?

Comment: There is only one imageview and i am setting it through pojo class

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> checkedImageSrc = extras.getIntArray("img");

Comment: can you share your adapter class ?